# Simplest way to "correct" an accidental use of mv instead of an hg mv?

Tags: bash, mercurial, mv, idioms

I have a tracked `foo`. Now, since I'm absent-minded, I've run:

```
mv foo bar
```

now, when I do `hg st`, I get:

```
! foo
? bar
```

I want to fix this retroactively - as though I'd done an `hg mv foo bar`.

Now, I could write a bash script which does that for me - but is there something better/simpler/smarter I could do?

Comment: For future mind absence : `alias mv='mv -i'`

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou: There was no overwriting, I just forgot to have mercurial note the move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `--after` option: `hg mv --after foo bar`

```
$ hg mv --help
hg rename [OPTION]... SOURCE... DEST

aliases: move, mv

rename files; equivalent of copy + remove

    Mark dest as copies of sources; mark sources for deletion. If dest is a
    directory, copies are put in that directory. If dest is a file, there can
    only be one source.

    By default, this command copies the contents of files as they exist in the
    working directory. If invoked with -A/--after, the operation is recorded,
    but no copying is performed.

    This command takes effect at the next commit. To undo a rename before
    that, see 'hg revert'.

    Returns 0 on success, 1 if errors are encountered.

options ([+] can be repeated):

 -A --after               record a rename that has already occurred
 -f --force               forcibly copy over an existing managed file
 -I --include PATTERN [+] include names matching the given patterns
 -X --exclude PATTERN [+] exclude names matching the given patterns
 -n --dry-run             do not perform actions, just print output
    --mq                  operate on patch repository

(some details hidden, use --verbose to show complete help)
```

Comment: Hmm, I missed that somehow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm doing right now;

```
#!/bin/bash

function die {
    echo "$1" >&2
    exit -1
}

(( $# == 2 )) || die "Usage: $0 <moved filename> <original filename>"
[[ -e "$1" ]]  || die "Not an existing file: $1"
[[ ! -e "$2" ]] || die "Not a missing file: $2"

hg_st_lines_1=$(hg st "$1" 2>/dev/null | wc -l)
hg_st_lines_2=$(hg st "$2" 2>/dev/null | wc -l)

(( ${hg_st_lines_1} == 1 )) || die "Expected exactly one line in hg status for $1, but got ${hg_st_lines_1}"
(( ${hg_st_lines_2} == 1 )) || die "Expected exactly one line in hg status for $2, but got ${hg_st_lines_2}"

[[ "$(hg st "$1" 2>/dev/null)" == \?* ]] || die "Mercurial does not consider $1 to be an unknown (untracked) file"
[[ "$(hg st "$2" 2>/dev/null)" =~ !.* ]] || die "Mercurial does not consider $2 to be a missing file"

mv $1 $2
hg mv $2 $1
```